# Ruby on Rails - node_modules file is too big

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to learn ruby on rails. I created a new project with Rails 6.1.2.1 for this purpose but it took more than 5 minutes. The problem is after creating the project, it creates a huge 100Mb+ dir which is called `node_modules` with every possible `node_package`. This does not make sense as the default behavior. Am I actually missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The `node_modules` are for your front-end stuff. Now Ruby on Rails supports webpacker with all goodies of NodeJS. It is already in .gitignore and it is normal behavior.

When you want to save your project, you can delete this folder and whenever you need you can use `yarn install` to get it back.

Answer (score 0):

You can create rails app without installing webpacker

--skip-webpack-install option of Rails new. It still includes the webpackergem in the Gemfile and sets up the resulting project with webpacker configuration (only rails webpacker:install is not run).